# Property already registered by 'ListView'

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-2012

I have this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

public static class SelectedItems
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsBehaviorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "SelectedItemsBehavior",
        typeof(SelectedItemsBehavior),
        typeof(ListView),
        null);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Items",
        typeof(IList),
        typeof(SelectedItems),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, ItemsPropertyChanged));

    public static void SetItems(ListView listView, IList list)
    {
        listView.SetValue(ItemsProperty, list);
    }

    public static IList GetItems(ListView listView)
    {
        return listView.GetValue(ItemsProperty) as IList;
    }

    private static void ItemsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var target = d as ListView;
        if (target != null)
        {
            CreateBehavior(target, e.NewValue as IList);
        }
    }

    private static void CreateBehavior(ListView target, IList list)
    {
        var behavior = target.GetValue(SelectedItemsBehaviorProperty) as SelectedItemsBehavior;
        if (behavior == null)
        {
            behavior = new SelectedItemsBehavior(target, list);
            target.SetValue(SelectedItemsBehaviorProperty, behavior);
        }
    }
}

public class SelectedItemsBehavior
{
    private readonly ListView _listView;
    private readonly IList _boundList;

    public SelectedItemsBehavior(ListView listView, IList boundList)
    {
        _boundList = boundList;
        _listView = listView;
        _listView.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
    }

    private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _boundList.Clear();

        foreach (var item in _listView.SelectedItems)
        {
            _boundList.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
    <ListView SelectionMode="Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding Computers}" Views:SelectedItems.Items="{Binding SelectedComputers}" BorderBrush="Transparent" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" />
        </ListView.Background>
    </ListView>
```

I've got an error of

> 'SelectedItemsBehaviour' property was already registered by
>   'Listview'.

I've used this code in two places on two separate `ListViews` and both give this error.

Why am I getting it, everything is static. I am using the MVVM design pattern.

Thanks,

Comment: I also had the same problem with a combo box behavior. [I have mentioned the fix in my blog](http://contractnamespace.blogspot.com/2014/04/default-text-on-wpf-combo-boxes.html), just in case if anyone else came across the same error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The third parameter to [RegisterAttached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597497.aspx) (`ownerType`) must always be the class that declares the property, which is `SelectedItems` here.

It is a common misunderstanding that this type is a potential "target" type of the property.

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsBehaviorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "SelectedItemsBehavior",
    typeof(SelectedItemsBehavior),
    typeof(SelectedItems), // here
    null);
```