# Sorting text column as numeric column WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, mvvm, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` which is binded to a collection of models. My model has a string property called `Position` which is of type string, but contains an integer value.

My problem is, when sorting this column values get sorted as `1, 10, 2` instead of `1, 2, 10`.

Is there anyway to handle this MVVM style without handling the `Sorting` event of the `DataGrid` in code-behind?
Bear in mind I cannot change the type of the property.

Comment: put an `int PositionNumber {get { return int.Parse(Position); } }` property in the model and use that instead.

Comment: @HighCore I have more than one property with this behavior and I'm looking for a more generic solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to do it in the code-behind, I think you will want a custom sort behavior, like shown in this SO post...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18218963/1246574

I know you said you don't want to break MVVM so you don't want to handle a sort event in the code-behind.  Even so, in case anyone else wants to know how to do it that way, this SO post shows how...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2130557/1246574

Comment: The attached behavior seems to be what I'm looking for. I'll check it out and report back. Thanks!