# Fix the first row in a DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am trying to keep one row in a DataGrid always on top while still being able to sort all other rows by columns (int and string columns).

The structure of my data provides a little help: The first column is named "Id", and the row that I am trying to keep on top always has the lowest Id of all Ids. This row contains aggregated values.

A typical DataGrid might look like this:

```
ID | Name | Result1 | Result2
5  | avg  |  2      | 5
6  | opt1 |  1      | 3
7  | opt2 |  3      | 7
```

There may be n columns and the number of columns will change in runtime. The DataGrid is bound to a ListCollectionView and I've also implemented a custom sorter based on [trilson86's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122751/wpf-datagrid-customsort-for-each-column):

```
    <DataGrid result:CustomSortBehaviour.AllowCustomSort="True" 
              IsReadOnly="True" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ResultDataView}">
    </DataGrid>
```

So far, using trilson86's soution, I managed to keep the first line on top when sorting. This is the handler in my CustomSortBehavior-class that prepares useful data chunks (for example the minimum-Id in the current DataGrid) for a custom sorter:

```
    private static void HandleCustomSorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
        if (dataGrid == null || !GetAllowCustomSort(dataGrid)) return;
        var listColView = dataGrid.ItemsSource as ListCollectionView;
        var min = listColView.Cast<DataRowView>().Min(x => x.Row[0]);
        var sorter = new MyComparer();
        e.Handled = true;
        var direction = (e.Column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;
        e.Column.SortDirection = sorter.SortDirection = direction;
        sorter.IdOfFirstRow = Convert.ToInt32(min);
        listColView.CustomSort = sorter;
    }
```

The custom sorter itself:

```
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        var rowView1 = x as DataRowView;
        var rowView2 = y as DataRowView;
        var row1 = rowView1.Row;
        var row2 = rowView2.Row;
        var row1Id = Convert.ToInt32(row1[0]);
        var row2Id = Convert.ToInt32(row2[0]);

        if (row1IdValue == IdOfFirstRow)
            return -1;

        if (row2IdValue == IdOfFirstRow)
            return 1;

        if (SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending) {
            return row2Id.CompareTo(row1Id); 
        }
        else
        {
            return row1Id.CompareTo(row2Id);
        }
    }
```

This is only half of a solution.. hardcoded as is, I can only sort by Id. Because columns will be added at runtime, I cannot, at design time, define all columns and attach a sorter according to the columns value type (int or string).

**How can I sort by all other columns while keeping the restriction that the row with the minimum Id stays on top?**

Comment: Why do you need the first row fixed at the top? I assume it's *not* showing header information, but I can't imagine what kind of *data* would need to stay at the top.

Comment: I've got a datatable where the first line below the headers displays aggregated information and all the other lines do not. So, whenever sorting, the requirement is that the first line containing the aggregated information should stay right below the headers.

Comment: I wouldn't store the aggregated information in the table itself, but in a separate view model (of which the model could be in the ExtendedProperties of the table if necessary). Then create a custom template for the DataGrid in which you add the aggregated information between the header and the actual rows.

Comment: That's a nice idea since it would keep my proprietary "model" cleaner. However, what I'm trying right now is to use a custom sort function. If that turns out not usable, I might try your idea [and would then reward you the bounty]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the [DisplayIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.displayindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get the column you are sorting.

```
private static void HandleCustomSorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
    if (dataGrid == null || !GetAllowCustomSort(dataGrid)) return;
    ListSortDirection direction = (e.Column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;
    ListCollectionView lcv = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemSource);
    int min = lcv.Cast<DataRowView>().Min(x => x.Row[0]);

    lcv.CustomSort = new CustomComparer(direction, e.Column.DisplayIndex, min); //DisplayIndex gets you your column
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

and then this comparer should do what you are looking for, not sort min ID row while sorting ints and strings in column.

```
public class CustomComparer : IComparer
{
     ListSortDirection _direction;
     int colNum;
     int _IdOfFirstRow;
     public CustomComparer(ListSortDirection direction, int colNum, int IdOfFirstRow)
     {
          _direction = _direction;
          _colNum = colNum;
          _IdOfFirstRow = IdOfFirstRow;
     }
     public int Compare(object x, object y)
     {
          DataRowView rowView1 = x as DataRowView;
          DataRowView rowView2 = y as DataRowView;
          int valX, valY;
          if (x == y)
             return 0;

          //Don't sort min Id
          var row1Id = Convert.ToInt32(rowView1[0]);
          var row2Id = Convert.ToInt32(rowView2[0]);

          if (row1Id == _IdOfFirstRow) 
              return -1;
          else if (row2Id == _IdOfFirstRow)
              return 1;

          string strX = rowView1[_colNum] as string;
          string strY = rowView2[_colNum] as string;
          bool ret1 = int.TryParse(strX, valX);
          bool ret2 = int.TryParse(strY, valY);

          if (ret1 == false && ret2 == false) //is a string
          {

               if (_direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
               {
                    return strX.CompareTo(strY);
               }
               else
               {
                    return strY.CompareTo(strX);
               }
          }
          else
          {
               if (_direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
               {
                    return valX.CompareTo(valY);
               }
               else
               {
                    return valY.CompareTo(valX);
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thats what I did in the meantime and it works just as supposed!