# Sorting DataGrid column containing different Types of cells throws ArgumentException

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid bound to a collection of items which have a field of type object which can contain anything ... bool, string or anything. But when I click on the column header to sort, an ArgumentException is thrown. I mean it makes complete sense but still how can I avoid this problem. All I want is to convert everything to string and compare them as strings. Using a converter does not help. I cannot change the ViewModel to do a ToString on the item's property, so I need a view only solution.

Here's some sample code:

XAML:

```
    <DataGrid
            ItemsSource="{Binding items}" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
            IsManipulationEnabled="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="Name"
                    IsReadOnly="True" 
                    Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="Content"              
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Binding="{Binding data, Converter={StaticResource toString}}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

C#:

```
public class MainViewModel : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        items = new ObservableCollection<OneItem>();

        items.Add(new OneItem { Name = "Tom", Height = 180, Weight = 75, Class = 2, data = false });
        items.Add(new OneItem { Name = "Dick", Height = 182, Weight = 83, Class = 3, data = true });
        items.Add(new OneItem { Name = "Harry", Height = 182, Weight = 83, Class = 3, data = "Sting" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<OneItem> items { get; private set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class OneItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public double Class { get; set; }

    public object data { get; set; }
}
```

Exception:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 55 : Cannot sort by 'data' InvalidOperationException:'System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compare two elements in the array. ---> System.ArgumentException: Object must be of type Boolean.
   at System.Boolean.CompareTo(Object obj)
   at System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)
   at MS.Internal.Data.SortFieldComparer.Compare(Object o1, Object o2)
   at System.Array.SorterGenericArray.SwapIfGreaterWithItems(Int32 a, Int32 b)
   at System.Array.SorterGenericArray.IntroSort(Int32 lo, Int32 hi, Int32 depthLimit)
   at System.Array.SorterGenericArray.IntrospectiveSort(Int32 left, Int32 length)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Array.SorterGenericArray.IntrospectiveSort(Int32 left, Int32 length)
   at System.Array.Sort(Array keys, Array items, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer comparer)
   at System.Array.Sort(Array array, IComparer comparer)
   at MS.Internal.Data.SortFieldComparer.SortHelper(ArrayList al, IComparer comparer)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataExtensionMethods.Sort(IList list, IComparer comparer)
   at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.PrepareLocalArray()
   at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.RefreshOverride()
   at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.RefreshInternal()
   at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.Refresh()
   at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.EndDefer()
   at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.DeferHelper.Dispose()
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.EndDefer()
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.DeferHelper.Dispose()
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.DefaultSort(DataGridColumn column, Boolean clearExistingSortDescriptions)'
```

Comment: The easiest approcach would be simply adding (directly, or by extending or inheritng from `OneItem`) a calculated property that simply returns `data.ToString()`, and bind your DataGridColumn to that property instead You also avoid using a Converter, that way.

Comment: Yeah the VM approach would have been the easiest but I do not want to clutter my VM for an issue which occurs at one insignificant place and my VM is used at several places for more imp. tasks.

Comment: Ok, I'm posting another solution, which is a tad more convoluted but is view-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approcach would be simply adding (directly, or by extending or inheritng or wrapping your `OneItem`) a calculated property that simply returns `data.ToString()`, and bind your DataGridColumn to that property instead. You also avoid using a Converter, that way.

But another way could be implementing DataGrid's custom sorting.

[Following the indications here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122751/wpf-datagrid-customsort-for-each-column) you can create attached properties to allow custom sorting in a per-column basis, and then you just need to create a ICustomSorter for your column. In this case, the ICustomSorter would be as simple as this:

```
public class ObjectSorter : ICustomSorter
{
    public System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection SortDirection { get; set; }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return x.ToString().CompareTo(y.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then declare one in your view Resources and set it to your column using the attached properties described in that link.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding items}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
          IsManipulationEnabled="False"
          behaviours:CustomSortBehaviour.AllowCustomSort="True">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <sort:ObjectSorter x:Key="MyObjectSorter" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Name"
                IsReadOnly="True" 
                Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn
                Header="Content"              
                IsReadOnly="True"
                Binding="{Binding data, Converter={StaticResource toString}}"
                behaviours:CustomSortBehaviour.CustomSorter="{StaticResource MyObjectComparer}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2):

I add DataDisplay property like this:

```
public class OneItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public double Class { get; set; }

    public object data { get; set; }

    public object DataDisplay
    {
        get
        {
            if (data == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            return data.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Then replace data by DataDisplay and remove the Converter in binding:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid
        ItemsSource="{Binding items}" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
        IsManipulationEnabled="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Name"
                IsReadOnly="True" 
                Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Header="Content"              
                IsReadOnly="True"
                Binding="{Binding DataDisplay}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

If you also want Converter. Let me know :)