# WPF Data Grid column sorting one way

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting

I have a WPF Datagrid with two columns that I would only like to be sorting ascending depending on which column is selected. If column "Name" is selected, the sorting is ascending on "Name", or, if column "Description" is selected instead, the sorting is ascending on Description. 
Neither of them should be able to be sorted descending (If the column is selected a second time, it should not switch the column from an Ascending sort to a Descending sort).

```
<DataGrid Name="Person" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn SortDirection="{Binding SortOrder, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Name" SortMemberPath="Name">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Some template info for displaying Name... -->
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn SortDirection="{Binding SortOrder, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Description" SortMemberPath="Description">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Some template info for displaying Description... -->
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid Name="Person">
```

Comment: OK ?!? Nice info, but what should we do with it ?

Comment: I want to know how to do this so that the user can select any column they want to sort by, but only let them sort the grid by that column in an Ascending manner.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show what you have done. Tell what your problem is, where are you stuck.

Comment: You are looking for attached properties / attached behaviors.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122751/wpf-datagrid-customsort-for-each-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up going with is a modification of a different answer

```
private void Person_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `Sorting` event of the `DataGrid`:

```
private void Person_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Column.SortDirection = System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending;
}
```

---

```
<DataGrid Name="Person" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}" Sorting="Person_Sorting" ...>
```

Comment: This helped! The solution that I ended up with was based off of this.